# Tensor product of Verma modules

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $M(\mu_1)$ and $M(\mu_2)$ be two Verma modules of lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl_2}$.

Why is the tensor product $M(\mu_1) \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} M(\mu_2)$ not finitely generated?

Comment: I think it is a fact of nature, but perhaps you are wanting a more philosophical explanation...

Comment: Yes please. I want the explanation.

Comment: @Jaynot Are things clear?

Comment: @Hanno I really appreciate your kind concern and good attitude to make sure you I figure it out. But I am afraid I couldn't so I just abandoned it for now. I didn't want to bother you any longer.

Comment: @Jaynot Please don't hesitate to ask further - the different natures of tensor products can be confusing in the beginning.

Comment: @Hanno Hi Hanno. I still haven't been able too compute the dimension of the weight spaces. Could you please if you have time show me? I just really want to understand it.

Comment: Just a note: You might confuse many people using this notation, since $L(\lambda)$ usually means the simple module with that highest weight rather than the Verma module (which is usually denoted one of $M(\lambda)$ or $\Delta(\lambda)$. The notation $V(\lambda)$ would make sense, but was for a long time used for the simples so that would be unfortunate, and as far as I can tell, hardly any modern sources use that notation). Out of curiosity: Where did you see them denoted this way?

Comment: @Jaynot The formula for the action of the Lie algebra on the tensor product implies that if you have weight vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ of weights $\lambda$ and $\mu$, then $v_1 \otimes v_2$ has weight $\lambda + \mu$.

Comment: @Jaynot This given, it follows that the weight spaces of the tensor product are of the form $(M \otimes N)_\nu=\oplus (M_\lambda \otimes N_\mu)$ where the sum runs over pairs $\lambda,\mu$ with $\nu=\lambda+\mu$.

Comment: @Jaynot Thus e.g. if you take the tensor product of the Verma $M(0)$ for $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ with itself, the dimension of the weight space $(M(0) \otimes M(0))_{-2m}$ is $m+1$ for each non-negative integer $m$.

Answer (score 4):

The tensor product *is* again locally ${\mathfrak U}({\mathfrak n}^+)$-finite, but it's no longer finitely generated. You can see this by working out the weight space dimensions - for a module in ${\mathscr O}({\mathfrak s}{\mathfrak l}_2)$, these are eventually constant.

Comment: I will try to work this out but I am bit confused about what you said cos I know from my basics that the tensor product of two finitely generated modules is also finitely generated. In our case here, the two Verma modules  both belong to category O, so I guess their tensor product should also be fintely generated. Could you shed more light on this? @Hanno

Comment: @Jaynot: Perhaps you are remembering a result from _commutative_ algebra here, where the tensor product is taken over the base ring?

Comment: Yes thats what I am thinking. I am currently taking a commutative algebra course.

Comment: @Jaynot: Note that tensor products of modules over Lie algebras are fundamentally different. You take the tensor product over the ground field, and the Lie algebra action comes from the Hopf algebra structure on ${\mathfrak U}({\mathfrak g})$.